Git like view for dataframe comparison
I have two dataframe set called df1 and df2.
I need to create a view in django template to compare these two dataframe in side by side. It should be looks like the git like comparison like below.

I have tried the below but didn't work
 views.py
    
                        # Convert DataFrames to lists of dictionaries for easier iteration
                        df1_data = df1.to_dict(orient='records')
                        df2_data = df2.to_dict(orient='records')
    
                        # Combine the data to be passed to the template
                        combined_data = list(zip(df1_data, df2_data))
    
                        return render(request, self.view_template,{
                                       'combined_data': combined_data
                                       }
                                      )

template

{% block content %}
<style>
        .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .column {
            flex: 1;
        }
    </style>

<div class="container">
    {% for row1, row2 in combined_data %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                {% for key, value in row1.items %}
                    <p>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                {% for key, value in row2.items %}
                    <p>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}

